Why the color of IDE element is different than I set?
I have my own theme (based on Dark). After I updated Visual Studio 2022 to 17.9.5 version a few colors of IDE elements are different than I set and I don't understand why.
I was trying to set it explicit from Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors or by using Color Theme Designer - I got the same result.
For better illustration I attach the screenshot of my code:

(the code is totally stupid, you don't analyze it :D)
As you can see, colors next to the definition are correct: ITest is yellow-ish, STest is green-ish, TKey and TValue next to method name is also yellow-ish.
But when they are used as parameters method then ITest is white, STest also but CTest or ETest is correct...
The same in comment - ITest, STest is white, but CTest or BaseClass is green-ish (ETest is yellow-ish) as I want.
The ITest on implmenetation list is also white but classes are green-ish.
Another strange things are: var in foreach is white, but in 'normal code' is blue, nameof operator/keyword is also white but typeof is blue - I want blue for all.
I found that the white color is used because Identifier field (from Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors) has that color. So when I change Identifier to red then I get.
But I don't understand why Identifier color is used at all.
When I change theme to Dark, then all white colors are not white. They are correct like you can expected and those colors do not use Identifer color. But in my theme, after the update VS something happen... something change...
Any suggestions? I don't know where I should start to resolve the issue.

I beleive this is a bug is VS, you might like to raise an issue on the Visual Studio Community Forum

This post was asked not too long ago, and I wonder if its possibly related.

Try disabling IntelliSense by the method in the post provided in the comment above:
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages, find and uncheck the "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information" options.
